# AWS trigger when an instance is available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I have created a workflow like this:

- Use requests for an instance creation through a API Gateway endpoint
- The gateway invokes a lamda function that executes the following code
- Generate a RDP with the public dns to give it to the user so that they can connect.

```
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    instances = ec2.create_instances(...)
    instance = instances[0]
    time.sleep(3)
    instance.load()
    return instance.public_dns_name
```

The problem with this approach is that the user has to wait almost 2 minutes before they were able to login successfully. I'm totally okay to let the lamda run for that time by adding the following code:

```
instance.wait_until_running()
```

But unfortunately the API gateway has a 29 seconds timeout for lambda integration. So even if I'm willing to spend it wouldn't work. What's the easiest way to overcome this?

Comment: Have you looked at `waiters`? Refer this document for more details: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html#waiters

Comment: The problem is not with waiting. The problem is the timeout of 29 seconds in API gateway but the wait_until_running() takes much more than that so the user will only see a request timeout.

Comment: What software is the user running - a web browser or custom code? How are you handling retrieving the password for the instance?

Comment: You can use Cloudwatch Event Rules to call a service that will send an email to your users when the Instance changes to Running state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My approach to accomplish your scenario could be Cloudwatch Event Rule.**

- The lambda function after Instance creation must store a kind of relation between the instance and user, something like this:

---

**Proposed table:**
*The table structure is up to you, but these are the most important columns.*

```
------------------------------
| Instance_id   |  User_Id   |
------------------------------
```

---

- Creates a CloudWatch Event Rule to execute a Lambda function.

Firstly, pick Event Type: `EC2 Instance State-change Notification` then select Specific state(s): `Running`:

[image]

Secondly, pick the target: `Lambda function`:

[image]

- Lambda Function to send email to the user.

That Lambda function will receive the `InstanceId`.  With that information, you can find the related `User_Id` and send the necessary information to the user. You can use the SDK to get information of your EC2 instance, for example, its `public_dns_name`.

**This is an example of the payload that will be sent by Cloudwatch Event Rule notification:**

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "6a7e8feb-b491-4cf7-a9f1-bf3703467718",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "111122223333",
  "time": "2015-12-22T18:43:48Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-12345678"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-12345678",
    "state": "running"
  }
}
```

That way, you can send the `public_dns_name` when your instance is totally in service.

**Hope it helps!**